# bootstrap navbar navbar-nav issues

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm trying to change my Navbar.

My actual website is https://demo.gozpeak.com , but I don't know if my navbar is very bootstrap-compliant ...  (feel free to comment).

For the moment, my new navbar looks like this :

```
<nav id="zpeakNavigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <a id="zpeakLogo" class="navbar-brand" href="index.php?page=home"><img src="views/images/gozpeak_small.png" alt="GoZpeak" title="GoZpeak!" /></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul id="zpeakNavbar" class="nav navbar-nav nav-pills navbar-right">
        <li class="btn navbar-btn pull-right">
          <a title="addevent" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalSelectQueryNotLogged"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"> Add event </span></a>
        </li>

        <li class="btn navbar-btn pull-right">
          <a title="registration" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalInscription"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"> Registration</span></a>
        </li>

        <li class="btn navbar-btn pull-right">
          <a title="connection" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalConnection"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"> Connection</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

My CSS :

```
#zpeakNavigation a {
  color:#669DD4!important;
  font-size: 12pt;
}

#zpeakNavigation a:hover {
  color: #DAE3E6!important;
}

#zpeakNavbar {
  width: 50%;
}

#zpeakNavbar li {
  margin-right: 3%;
}

#zpeakLogo img {
  margin-left: 14%;
  width: 74%;
}
```

The main issue is that, when I resize screen (for md or sm, for example), the navbar-nav is broken...  one button go under the bar, then one another, etc...

In this case, I would like that the 3 buttons keep aligned, (ideally move at the same level as much as possible...).

For example, almost like this site  (except I will add a searchbar after that) :

https://nounouenligne.fr

Answer (score 0):

```
replace this code to style:

#zpeakNavigation a {
  color:#669DD4!important;
  font-size: 12pt;
}

#zpeakNavigation a:hover {
  color: #DAE3E6!important;
}

#zpeakNavbar {
  width: 100%;
}

#zpeakNavbar li {
  margin-right: 3%;
}

#zpeakLogo img {
  margin-left: 14%;
  width: 74%;
}

/*responsive*/


@media (max-width: 767px) {
#zpeakNavbar {
  width: 100%;
}
#zpeakNavbar li {
    margin-right: 3%;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}
}
```